# Python / Pygame Platformer

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game in `pygame`, and as an exercise in the [tutorial I'm watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V_Q0M15274), the guy has had me make 2 different colored blocks, at different places on the screen. That worked just fine, but then he showed me how to change one of those blocks with a .png picture. I followed everything exactly, but for some reason, the window opens for like half a second, and I get an error.

I've watched the video multiple times, but I just can't get it to work. Here is my full code, as it is now.

```
import pygame
from colors import *

class Block( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

def __init__( self, color = blue, width = 64, height = 64 ):

    super( Block, self ).__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ) )

    self.image.fill( color )

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def set_position( self, x, y ):
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y

def set_image( self, filename = None ):
    if ( filename is not None ):

        self.image = pygame.image.load( filename )

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
pygame.init()

window_size = window_width, window_height = 640, 480
window = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size, pygame.RESIZABLE )

pygame.display.set_caption( "Test Game" )

window.fill( white )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
frames_per_second = 60


block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

a_block = Block()
a_block.set_image( "brick.png" )
a_block.set_position( window_width/2, window_height/2 )

another_block = Block( red )
another_block.set_position( 100, 100 )

block_group.add( a_block, another_block )

block_group.draw( window )

running = True

while ( running ):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    clock.tick( frames_per_second )
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

If anyone can help me, I would love it. Thanks.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: The indentation of the code you posted is messed-up.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about the indentation. I tried to upload it, as is, but the website kept telling me to indent it with 4 spaces. It was very frustrating. I can promise you though that all of the indentation is correct. And it gave me hell to try and copy and paste the error, Zizouz212. Let me try again. It was, Traceback (most recent call last) : Line 45, in <module>  a_block.set_image( "brick.png" ). And then it also says, line 24, in set_image self.image = pygame.image.load( filename ) pygame.error: Couldn't open brick.png

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can solve the problem here.

- Method 1:

Move brick.png into the **same directory** as your program (.py) file.

- Method 2:

Specify the path along with the image name, for example:
If brick.png was at "/home/username/ProgramFolder/brick.png", then instead of typing

```
a_block.set_image( "brick.png" )
```

you would type

```
a_block.set_image( "/home/username/ProgramFolder/brick.png" )
```

If neither of these methods work, you have a unique problem.  For additional information, refer to http://www.pygame.org/docs/index.html.